# How can I crop an image with a border-radius when hover

Tags: html, css

How can I crop a image with a border-radius of 56px when hover?

Like this

[image]

(just mine I want to have a css defined border of 56px)

```css
 .image-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
 }
 
 img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      border-radius: 50px
      transition: .5s;
    }
    img:hover {
      
    }
```

```html
    <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://fujifilm-x.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/gfx100s_sample_04_thum-1.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: Without HTML and CSS this is our of scope for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use clip-path:

```css
img {
  clip-path: inset(0 round 50px);
  transition: .5s;
}
img:hover {
  /* crop by 10px */
  clip-path: inset(10px round 50px);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/300/300">
```

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss "a poorly asked question": that's your point of view that I don't share. Search in SO (or the internet) and let me know if you can easily find a solution to the asked question. If so, you can call it a poorly asked question otherwise it's a valid question because the solution is not trivial. Also note that not all the questions require a code inside the question. A code is needed when the question is about "debugging" a code or asking why "a code is not working"

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example : *When asking a debugging question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code as text in your question that prospective answerers can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.* ---> note the **When asking a debugging question** and **to reproduce the problem** which is not the purpose of this question

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss also read this to understand that the question you closed is a valid one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259947/8620333